# Why filter treats this and arr different in Array.prototype.filter? JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays

Clarification from start: this is not a matter of regular function or arrow function difference, my question is `this` vs `array` in `Array.prototype.filter`

I am wondering why does

```
this[index + 1]
```

give a different result than:

```
arr[index + 1]
```

Ok let me clarify, the functions look like this:

```
let words = ['spray', 'limit', 'exuberant', 'destruction', 'elite', 'present'];

let newWords = words.filter((word, index, arr) =>  {
    arr[index + 1] += ' extra';
    return word.length > 6;
})

// same as the one above but with using this

let newWordsThis = words.filter((word, index) => {
    this[index + 1] += ' extra';
    return word.length > 6;
})

// Same as the one above but with a function

let newWordsThisFunc = words.filter(function(word, index) {
    this[index + 1] += ' extra';
    return word.length > 6;
})
```

Knowing that this refers to the object the method is casted on, why are they different? here are my result:

```
newWords: limit extra,exuberant extra,destruction extra,elite extra,present extra
newWordsThis: limit extra,exuberant extra,destruction extra,elite extra,present extra,undefined extra
newWordsThisFunc:limit extra,exuberant extra,destruction extra,elite extra,present extra,undefined extra
```

I probably missed something when I was learning about `this`, but I don't know what... Please let me know if I need to clarify something.

Comment: `=>` functions do not set `this` like traditional functions do.

Comment: Wait you are saying that if this was a function, not an arrow function, the values would have been the same?

Comment: Well I *might* be able to say that, but I can't remember off-hand how `this` works with `.filter()`. I can however say that `=>` functions do not ever set `this`; it remains the value it has outside of the `=>` definition.

Comment: Just to make sure I understand this: _=> functions do not ever set `this`; it remains the value it has outside of the => definition_, by `this` you mean array functions can use the `this` object/array but it is not able to change it right?

Comment: No.  The distinction is between functions defined with the `function` keyword and functions defined with `=>`.  It doesn't have anything to do with how the functions are *used*.

Comment: Oh, and as to the value of `this` in the callback, if you use a `function` function (as opposed to a `=>` function) the value of `this` will be either `undefined`, or, if a second argument is passed to `.filter()` (and many of the other Array methods), then that will be used as `this`. Thus `arr.filter(someFunction, arr)` will guarantee that `arr` itself will be the value of `this`. Those functions generally pass `arr` as the third argument to the callback, so setting `this` is not often useful.

Comment: This makes a lot of sense now, it seems like the keyword `this` was bad usage from the start so they added another method i.e. `array`, which is optimized to not have these silly mistakes. Thank you again.